# trying to group de Json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures

i have been trying to group de JSON data by date and increment the like with the same date. But, i can't figure out how to code the part where if they have the same date and increment the likes with the same date.

Here's the JSON data.

```
var allIdDate =var allIdDate = [
{
  "date"  : 'sep, 22 2015',
  "likes" : 2
},
{
  "date"  : 'sep, 22 2015',
  "likes" : 10
},
{
  "date"  : 'sep, 21 2015',
  "likes" : 4
}
```

],

Here's my code, i am using the tableDate[] to keep track of the date then compare with AllIdDate[], to see if they have the same date.

```
var tableDate = [];
var groupByDate = [];
for(var j = 0; j < allIdDate.length ; j++){

   if(tableDate.indexOf(allIdDate[j].date) != -1){
      console.log(true)
      //if same date,then increment the likes that correspond with the same date.

    }else{
      console.log(false)

      tableDate[j] = allIdDate[j].date;
      groupByDate[j] = ({"date": allIdDate[j].date, " likes": allIdDate[j].likes})

      console.log("loop" + j + "" + groupByDate)
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't valid JSON or a valid JS array.

Comment: tableDate is empty because..?

Comment: sorry i didnt mention, i use the empty Tabledate to keep track of the date @ergonaut

Comment: @Andy , i input it manually

Answer (score 0):

This proposal features an [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in combination with [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Some).

```js
var allIdDate = [{
        "date": 'sep, 22 2015',
        "likes": 2
    }, {
        "date": 'sep, 22 2015',
        "likes": 10
    }, {
        "date": 'sep, 21 2015',
        "likes": 4
    }], 
    grouped = allIdDate.reduce(function (r, a) {
        !r.some(function (b) {
            if (a.date === b.date) {
                b.likes += a.likes;
                return true;
            }
        }) && r.push(a);
        return r;
    }, [])

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```